# Maven EAR: ejb module + application client (app client) module

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

I want to create an EAR project that consists of an EJB 3.1 module and an app client module, the app client talking to the ejb module through @Remote interface... I have done this many times in the past with ANT but I would like to do it with Maven

I've been googeling it for days and i have found some workarounds but i havent found a maven-app-client-plugin...

I cant find the jira to raise this as an enhancement, does anyone know if this exists or how to start if one wants to contribute to this.... how to tauch basis with the maven crew, etc.

Pablo.

Comment: Have you read these two links: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html + http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/ejb-client-dependency.html

Comment: yes, i read them, but is not what we were after.

Comment: this is what we are after: http://code.google.com/p/maven-car-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally contacted Stephane Nicolle, the person who developed Maven Ear plugin and he just created a maven-acr-plugin Java EE app clients and accomodated Maven EAR plugin to recognize a new app-client packaging type.

So as of Maven EAR plugin 2.6, there is official maven support for Java EE app clients

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically that this is an EAR Project i would recommend to use the [Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/).

Comment: I finally contacted the person in charged of Maven Ear plugin and he just created a maven-acr-plugin specially designated for this type of EAR module that had not been taken into consideration till now.

Answer (score 1):

And Here it is:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-acr-plugin/

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/using-app-client.html